# Python3: function call from pressing tkinter.button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please note that this is written in python 3

I am using Tkinter and am trying to call the foo-function by pressing the button in the tk-window and get "Hello World!" printed, what am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
window1 = Tk()

class WidgetCreate(object):

    def __init__(self, widget_type, window_num, text_str, fun, numr, numc):
        self.obj = Button(window_num, text=text_str, command=lambda: fun)
        self.obj.grid(row=numr, column=numc)

def foo():
    print("Hello World!")       

but1 = WidgetCreate("Button", window1, "This Button 1", foo, 1, 1)

window1.mainloop()
```

The button is visible in the to-window however when pressed nothing happens :(

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, it would be nice if you [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, There! Done! :)

Comment: The delay is no problem. Thanks, I commented only because you could have forgotten / not found it as new user. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the parenthesis in your `command` argument to `Button`. So your lambda function doesn't call the function you want. It has to be:

```
self.obj = Button(window_num, text=text_str, command=lambda: fun())
```

Or even simpler you do it without the lambda function and give `fun` directly as argument:

```
self.obj = Button(window_num, text=text_str, command=fun)
```

Comment: That little error took me 2 whole hours to notice. Thank you!

Comment: It's even better if you use the second way, because the `lambda` thing is not necessary.

Comment: Typically you'll only need a `lambda` if you have to pass arguments to a function. If you had to tell `foo` what to print, you'd have to do `command=lambda: fun("Hello, world!")` but if you can just call the function then there's no reason to wrap it inside another function :)